# Zeppelin Shiro LDAP Configuration

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, shiro, apache-zeppelin

I am attempting to restrict access to zeppelin based on an AD group or organizational unit.  However, I am unsuccessful with my configuration.

I have an active directory implemented using Simple AD in AWS and the domain is called corp.example.com

I created three users, two groups, one organizational unit.

The groups are called Access and NoAccess
The users are called AccessUser1, NoAccessUser1, AccessOrgUser1
The organizational unit is called AccessOrg

AccessUser1 is a memberOf Access
NoAccessUser1 is a memberOf NoAccess
AccessOrgUser1 is created under the OU AccessOrg

I am able to log in using any user with the following configuration:

```
### A sample for configuring LDAP Directory Realm
ldapRealm = org.apache.zeppelin.realm.LdapGroupRealm
ldapRealm.contextFactory.url = ldap://<UrlHere>
ldapRealm.contextFactory.authenticationMechanism = simple
```

I am unable to log in using any user with the following configuration:

```
### A sample for configuring LDAP Directory Realm
ldapRealm = org.apache.zeppelin.realm.LdapGroupRealm
## search base for ldap groups (only relevant for LdapGroupRealm):
ldapRealm.contextFactory.environment[ldap.searchBase] = ou=Users,dc=CORP,dc=EXAMPLE,dc=COM
ldapRealm.contextFactory.url = ldap://<UrlHere>
ldapRealm.userDnTemplate = uid={0},ou=Users,dc=CORP,dc=EXAMPLE,dc=COM
ldapRealm.contextFactory.authenticationMechanism = simple
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to configure `[users]` or `[roles]` as those are for basic authentication.

You will need to configure the `activedirectoryrealm` options and the `ldaprealm` options. 
(referring to: https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/security/shiroauthentication.html#5-groups-and-permissions-optional)

Change

```
uid={0},ou=Users,dc=CORP,dc=EXAMPLE,dc=COM
```

to

```
CN={0},ou=Users,dc=CORP,dc=EXAMPLE,dc=COM
```

You will also need to populate `activeDirectoryRealm.systemUsername` and `activeDirectoryRealm.systemPassword`.

This will allow you to designate groups from your AD that can login.